# How to make entries from column appear as row title

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a hospital database which looks something like this

```
id | patient_name | admitDate  | DischargeDate |RoomCategory
1  | john         |3/01/2011   | 5/01/2011     |Category1
2  | lisa         |3/01/2011   | 4/01/2011     |Category2
3  | ron          |5/01/2011   | 10/01/2011    |Category1
4  | howard       |6/01/2012   | 10/01/2012    |Category3
5  | john         |6/05/2011   | 7/05/2011     |Category4
6  | rammy        |6/02/2011   | 7/03/2011     |Category4
```

I have to calculate the number of patients in hospital on each day (both admit and discharge date to be counted) and group them by category

Suppose on 3/01/2011 we have 2 patients, one in category 1 and one in category 2 on 4/01/2011 we again have same 2 patients but on 5/01/2011 lisa (id 2) is discharged so we only have 1 patient from category 1  but now ron (id 3) is also admitted so now we also have to count him.

The output should look something like this

```
Date      | Category1 | Category2  | Category3 |Category4  
3/01/2011 |      1    |     1      |     0     |    0   
4/01/2011 |      1    |     1      |     0     |    0   
5/01/2011 |      2    |     0      |     0     |    0
```

I am not able to figure out how to list all the dates which might have a patient, because the actual table is huge and a lot of dates don't have any patient. I also am not able to get how will I count distinctively to get count under each category.

I have 15 categories in total in my actual table so using where for each one of them separately wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: I didn't "delete" it, you can't comment on deleted questions. As for not being able to use `PIVOT` then use a conditional aggregate. I have opened this for you again, but this is just a duplicate of the above.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for opening, i am reading the links you sent maybe they help

Comment: @Larnu i feel question is dead now, views not increasing :(

Comment: After 21 minutes... Seriously...? Have patience... Since you posted your question, only 1 more question related to SQL Server has been posted... [so] isn't a free coding service, don't treat it like one.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here. 1 you need a calendar table, and then 2 a pivot. I suggest, if I am honest, you invest in creating a calendar table firstly, but I use an inline one here. Then you can use pivoting to convert the values to columns. I use conditional aggregation here, as it is transferable and less restrictive.

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(1,'john  ',CONVERT(date,'3/01/2011'),CONVERT(date,'5/01/2011 '),'Category1'),
            (2,'lisa  ',CONVERT(date,'3/01/2011'),CONVERT(date,'4/01/2011 '),'Category2'),
            (3,'ron   ',CONVERT(date,'5/01/2011'),CONVERT(date,'10/01/2011'),'Category1'),
            (4,'howard',CONVERT(date,'6/01/2012'),CONVERT(date,'10/01/2012'),'Category3'),
            (5,'john  ',CONVERT(date,'6/05/2011'),CONVERT(date,'7/05/2011 '),'Category4'),
            (6,'rammy ',CONVERT(date,'6/02/2011'),CONVERT(date,'7/03/2011 '),'Category4'))V(id,patient_name,admitDate,DischargeDate,RoomCategory)
GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(admitDate), MAX(DischargeDate)) FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --UP to 1000 days. Add more cross joins for more days
Calendar AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, YT.MinAdmitDate) AS D
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(admitDate) AS MinAdmitDate FROM dbo.YourTable) YT)
SELECT C.D AS [Date],
       COUNT(CASE YT.RoomCategory WHEN 'Category1' THEN 1 END) AS Category1,
       COUNT(CASE YT.RoomCategory WHEN 'Category2' THEN 1 END) AS Category2,
       COUNT(CASE YT.RoomCategory WHEN 'Category3' THEN 1 END) AS Category3,
       COUNT(CASE YT.RoomCategory WHEN 'Category4' THEN 1 END) AS Category4
FROM Calendar C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON C.D >= YT.admitDate
                               AND C.D <= DischargeDate
GROUP BY C.D;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6411ff4d15580b34bf6a67b446cd0132) *Note that that results might not be what you expect as DB Fiddle defaults to American, and you provide an ambiguous date format and I don't provide an explicit style in the `CONVERT` functions.*